# How to know if man pages are written in my language?

Tags: man, locale, documentation, language

I know my language hindi is in my locale. I have tried to access the hindi man page using this command-

```
man -Lhi man
```

But it returns english man pages. So I want to find out how to know if man pages I have are translated in my language? I also tried to do it for russian man pages as mentioned in other answers but it is returning only english man pages. I have man-db-2.x package.

Answer (score 2):

Man pages translated into Hindi should be shipped in `/usr/share/man/hi`. Unfortunately it appears that there are *very* few man pages translated into Hindi; in Debian, a search across the whole distribution (`apt-file search /usr/share/man/hi`) only lists two man pages, for `deja-dup`.

Searching for Russian translations finds more man pages: 211 by my count in Debian, including 11 in `man-db`.